# check the number of digits in a number

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have file contains numbers. where i have to loop through and check if each number  in the file consist of 11 digits. 
  if a number found consist of less/more than 11 digits  then this number should be written into output file.

Here is my attempt:

```
number="$(< all_numbers.txt)"
for numbers in $number ;
do 
    if [${#numbers} == 11];
    then  
        echo $numbers = "${#numbers}" > num.txt;
    fi; 
done;
```

When i run my code, I get the following error:

> -bash: [11: command not found

Comment: Did you try to add a space between the `[` and the `$`?

Comment: yes but i get ````-bash: [: missing `]'````

Comment: And with a space before the closing `]`?

Comment: it works!! but the condition in if statement doesn't evaluated

Comment: Note that all semicolons are useless in this script.

Comment: I find simply awful that `for numbers in $number`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix uses `-eq` to compare numbers. "==" are used for strings. 
And I think you can avoid most of the semicolons.

So your script should be:

```
number="$(< all_numbers.txt)"
for numbers in $number
do 
    if [ ${#numbers} -eq 11 ];  then  
        echo $numbers = "${#numbers}" > num.txt
    fi
done
```

> **Update**

If you need elements that are Not Equal to (Greater or Lesser than) 11, simply change the condition to `[ ${#numbers} -ne 11 ]`

---

> **Update 2**: Adding additional checks:

```
number="$(< all_numbers.txt)"
for numbers in $number
do 
    if [[ ! ${#numbers} =~ ^93 ]] ; then
        echo $numbers = "${#numbers}" > num93.txt
    fi
    if [ ${#numbers} -ne 11 ];  then  
        echo $numbers = "${#numbers}" > num.txt
    fi
done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: want to put all numbers have less than or greater than 11 digits in one external file

Comment: ```` if [ ! ${#numbers} -eq 11 ]; ```` helps

Comment: see the updated answer. you can simply use `-ne` instead of `-eq`

Comment: how can i add checks like checking if the number starts with 93? if not add this number to num.txt (the output file)

Comment: you can use `elif` (else if ) conditions to do it.. See my updated answer..

Comment: okay. got your point. will need to think about the condition. probably a regular expression?

Comment: i think so, since i need to check and report  two things,1st the numbers -ne 11 and check if i have numbers not started with 93

Comment: what if the first condition is executed? second (elif) would be ignored. right?

Comment: in fact, I want to check both conditions. ie check if a number doesn't starts with 93 then copy it to output text file. ALSO, check if it consists of -ne 11. in other words: my numbers should starts with 93 and each number should be of 11 digits if not report those numbers into output file

Answer (score 0):

You say that the number should be written to the output file, if it does **not** consist of 11 digits. You have to invert the logic.

Since you seem to use bash, one of many ways to do this would be

```
(( ${#numbers} == 11 )) || echo $number >num.txt
```

Note that this would consider 00000000001 as 11-digit-number. Your posting doesn't clarify whether this is really what you want to achieve.

Note also that this solution, like your approach, does not check whether the data is really a number. A string of 11 letters would also be considered as number.

Of course you could also get rid of the loop completely by writing

```
grep -vE '^.{11}$' >num.txt
```

If you want to also check for numbers and filter out non-digits, you could do

```
grep -vE '^[0-9]{11}$' >num.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use double negatives when testing numbers so that non-numbers get properly rejected:

```
for number in $(cat all_numbers.txt)
do 
    if ! [ "$number" -lt 10000000000 ] 2>/dev/null
    then  
        echo "$number = '${#number}'"
    fi
done > num.txt
```

I've change the variable names a bit since you had a pluralized "numbers" refer to each individual number.  This code has a singular `$number` to indicate each iteration from the input file.  I also used math to ensure that we only count numbers with eleven digits (greater to or equal to 10000000000) but then use the same variable length calculation as the original question when it comes to displaying the output.

I'm guessing you don't want to overwrite the file each time, so I moved your output to outside the loop.  You can also use `>> num.txt` at the end of the echo line, but that'll actually open the file once per number in the input file, which is inefficient.

The code I've written here is also POSIX compatible (no [bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), it'll work fine in [dash](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/)).  Note, old commercial UNIXes may complain about numbers larger than 2³¹ (the max signed 32-bit integer).